# Calling a function , when element is Live

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i call a function when element is live, i think we just raise a function by raising an event by live..

```
$('#a').live('click',function(){
  //some code
});
```

but i need a function to be called when element is lived,Any Idea.

The context is

> initially i dont have a select box , if i got a particular select box
>   then i want call a function that pushes result into it..

Comment: What do you mean by "i need a function to be called when element is lived"?

Comment: @Adil initially i dont have a select box , if i got a particular select box then i want call a function that pushes result into it..

Comment: `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use on delegate event...

```
$(document).on("click",'#a',function(){
   alert(clicked);
});
```

however,it is always recommended that you use the closest static elements that are in the HTML markup, then `$(document)` for better performance.. you can read more about on delegate event [here](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html)..

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page

Answer (score 0):

Live is deprecated and removed on jQuery 1.9. Use `.on()`

This enable click on any element with id #a added after page is loaded

```
$(document).on('click','#a',function(){

//Code here

});
```